# How to select href from JSON object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have trouble with json. I have json object which look like this:

```
{main: "<a href="www.google.com"><img src="google_logo.png"></a>"}
```

this  is just only part of my code for example but I select "main" object by this code json.main and then I selected all link with image. What I need is select href attribute but I do not know how.

Can you someone help me with this?

Thank your for help.

Answer (score 3):

You can create elements from the string and get the attribute from it:

```
var href = $(json.main).attr('href');
```

Comment: Oh thanks that works exactly as I need. Thank for fast help. I thought that I have to use .attr('href') but I forget to add $(json.main) part. Again thanks for help.

Comment: we can use  `$(json.main a).attr('href');` too

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON data contains HTML data. It's probably best to turn the HTML data into a proper DOM and use jQuery to work on it:

```
var main = yourJsonObject.main;
var $html = $(main);
var href = $html.attr('href');
```

Answer (score 0):

Guffa's method might be a little expensive, creating jQuery objects, if you have to do this en masse.
Try:

```
var the_href_part = json.main.match(/href="([^"]*?)"/)[1]
```

and if you're not sure if there'll be spaces before and after "=" sign:

```
var the_href_part = json.main.match(/href[ ]*=[ ]*"([^"]*?)"/)[1]
```

Answer (score -1):

Try appending

```
.getElementByTagName("a").getAttribute("href")
```